# Embeding compilation date into source (Like C __DATE__)

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to embed compilation date into compiled Action Script 3 file (like in C's `__DATE__` preprocessor constant)?

Is it possible to do it with custom date format?

I am using Flex for compilation

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656827/can-actionscript-tell-when-a-swf-was-published/4160717#4160717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joony's answer will work, but it's a bit of a hack. I don't know if it's officially supported.

If you are compiling with Ant (or command line or other script) then you can pass the date as a compiler argument.

Compiler arg:

```
 mxmlc -define+=CONFIG::compiledAt,'2011-01-17 17:05:01'
```

AS3 code:

```
 public static const COMPILED_AT:String = CONFIG::compiledAt;
```