# Compile date of swf module

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I implemented this code ([Can ActionScript tell when a SWF was published?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656827/can-actionscript-tell-when-a-swf-was-published/14877633#14877633)) in my main swf file in my project. It works great. However I load many modules in my application. These modules get compiled as needed to make changes. I would like to be able to get the compile date for the module that is currently loaded.

Basically I have one main Flex "Application" It then loads and unloads various modules (individual swf files) as needed based on user choices. I need to be able to put a control on each of these modules that will get the date that specific swf file was compiled.

Is there a way to pass the current swf file to the function to get the compile date of that swf?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `Loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytes` property, the `Loader` object being the one you used to load the SWF file.

You could change your function to accept the bytes of the SWF file as a parameter:

```
getCompilationDate(bytes:Array):void{
    ...
}

getCompilationDate(stage.loaderInfo.bytes)
getCompilationDate(moduleLoader.contentLoaderInfo.bytes)
```

Comment: So if I am in the loaded module, how do I reference the moduleLoader for the currently loaded module?

Comment: From inside the module, I believe you can use `stage.loaderInfo`.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I moved getCompilationDate() into a test module, and called it from a button. It returns the last compile time of the parentApplication SWF file, not the moduleLoader loaded swf file.

Comment: I am using the mdlModule:ModuleLoader object to load my modules. the ModuleLoader object does not appear to have a contentLoaderInfo property. I get a 1119 error when compiling mdlModule.contentLoaderInfo.

Comment: It looks like the ModuleManager and related classes hide the loader as a private field.

Comment: Bummer... Is it possible to create my own class, extending ModuleLoader, and make that field public?

Comment: I don't think so since it's private. Maybe you could load the SWF again using a `URLLoader` and `URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY`, ready you what you need and then get rid of everything.

Comment: When I have the chance, I will rewrite my code to use urlLoader, and then moduleLoader, as moduleLoader will take the byteArray imported from urlLoader instead of the url itself. Thus it will remove the only problem I have in using this approach which is the time it would take to load the module twice.