# How to find out the compilation time of an swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

How can I find out when excactly SWF was created?
Is there any free decompiler that can do the job?
Thank you.

Comment: This [has already been answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656827/can-actionscript-tell-when-a-swf-was-published) it seems.

Comment: Yes. But I've seen only question about how to get the timestamp in actionscipt. That's not what i need

Comment: Fair enoguh. What about [this answser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3795924/2631715) though?

Comment: why dont you just right click and go to properties-> date modified?

Comment: on the actuall .swf file that is

Comment: What do you need to get the timestamp in? e.g. if not actionscript...

Comment: @avanderw I need the timestamp for myself. I have a variety of .swf files with equal names, and I need to understand which was compiled first etc.

Comment: @momijigari does it need to be automated? Are you looking for a coded solution?

Answer (score 0):

Examining the creation/modification date with your operating system should work, especially if it was created on your computer. To display that, right-click/Properties, or option-i on the Mac.

(If these dates have been modified, the link provided by Gama11 ([Can ActionScript tell when a SWF was published?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656827/can-actionscript-tell-when-a-swf-was-published/3795924#3795924)) shows the swf contains the generation date encrypted somewhere, so in theory you can find or write an program to display that, or perhaps use an hexadecimal viewer).

Answer (score 0):

SWF is an archive of some sort ("SWFc" with LZMA compression?), which can be opened with 7-Zip. This archive contains a Metadata file (XML) containing the date the SWF was created.

On Windows I right clicked the SWF, [7-Zip] > [Open Archive...]
The SWF contained another SWF, so I repeated the process (without extracting the original archive).

Within that SWF, I found a bunch of cryptically named files (just numbers for names). However, each file has a "Comment" field in the archive. Find the file with the Comment "Metadata" (in my case it was the 2nd from the top, named 1.77). This is an XML file, which should contain a <xmp:CreateDate> tag.